# Jelly bean notification actions disabled

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, action, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm building an app that shows a notification with two options "Dim" and "Full" when a BroadcastReceiver is called. Each of this buttons broadcasts an action.

So far everything is possible to do, right?

The problem is that the buttons shown on the notification do not respond to the tap but the whole notification does (if I click on the icon or text instead of the button).

I have this function to build the notification:

```
private Notification buildReleaseNotification(NotificationManager nManager, Context context) {

    Notification.Builder builder = new Builder(context);
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.rate_star_big_half_holo_dark, "Dim", buildPendingIntent(context, DIM));
    builder.addAction(R.drawable.rate_star_big_on_holo_dark, "Full", buildPendingIntent(context, FULL));

    builder.setContentTitle("Car notification");
    builder.setContentText("Freed");
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setOngoing(true);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    return notification;
}
```

and it is called when receiving a broadcast:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Notification noty = null;
    noty = buildReleaseNotification(context);
    startService(context, RELEASE);

    if (noty != null) {
        nManager.notify(ChangeLockService.GLOBAL_TAG, ID, noty);
    }

}
```

------ edit

Just noticed that the following function returns null... So, how can I build a pending intent to perform a broadcast?

```
private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(Context context, String action) {

        Intent i = new Intent(action);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, i, Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
        return pi;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code to `buildPendingIntent()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare question updated. Thank you!

Comment: Are you saying that the buttons don't even seem to respond to touch (i.e. no momentary highlight on press) or that your broadcast is never received?

Comment: Neither of them are working...

Answer (score 1):

When creating the intent through

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, i, Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
```

caused it to return null.
According to the documentation, I understood that the flag `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING` would replace any pending intent that already existed for that button. If I send no flags then everything works fine:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, i, 0);
```